# Wordpress Paid user Registration

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some content in my website which I want to show to paid user only.

1.To achieve this I want to register two types of subscribers, default and paid.

2.Default user can register simply using default user registration form.

3.I want to add paid user Registration form, so that I can make get paid user registration.

4.Then I want to make pages visible to only paid user.

5.If user is default subscriber I want to hide paid content from the user. Is there any plugin to register paid user. So that I can make pages visible to paid user only.

I am using wordpress version 3.7
And I know least of php coding.
Any simple approach....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try [Paid Memberships Pro](http://wordpress.org/plugins/paid-memberships-pro/) with Flexible content control by Membership Level, Reports, Affiliates and Discounts.

In Which you can Set up unlimited membership levels and provide restricted access to pages, posts, categories, videos, forums, downloads, support, single "a la carte" page access, and more. Paid Memberships Pro is flexible enough to fit the needs of almost all online and offline businesses. It works great out of the box, but is easy for developers to customize to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple approach a plugin is often the best way forward. I would start with looking at this one. i am not affiliated with this plugin.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/s2member/